# Terraform Provider issue: registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I current have code that I have been using for quiet sometime that calls a custom S3 module.  Today I tried to run the same code and I started getting an error regarding the provider.

> ╷ │ Error: Failed to query available provider packages │  │ Could not
> retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/s3:
> provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
> │ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/s3 │  │ All modules should specify
> their required_providers so that external consumers will get the
> correct providers when using a module. To see which modules │ are
> currently depending on hashicorp/s3, run the following command: │
> terraform providers

Doing some digging seems that terraform is looking for a module **registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/s3**, which doesn't exist.

So far, I have tried the following things:

- Validated that the S3 Resource code meets the standards of the upgrade Hashicorp did to 4.x this year. Plus I have been using it for a couple of months with no issues.
- Delete .terraform directory and rerun terraform init (No success same error)
- Delete .terraform directory and .terraform.hcl lock and run terraform init -upgrade (No Success)
- I have tried to update my provider's file to try to force an upgrade (no Success)
- I tried to change the provider to >= current version to pull the latest version with no success

Reading further, it refers to a caching problem of the terraform modules.  I tried to run **terraform providers lock** and received this error.

> Error: Could not retrieve providers for locking │  │ Terraform failed
> to fetch the requested providers for darwin_amd64 in order to
> calculate their checksums: some providers could not be installed: │ -
> registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/s3: provider registry
> registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named
> registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/s3.

Kind of at my wits with what could be wrong.  below is a copy of my version.tf which I changed from providers.tf based on another post I was following:

**version.tf**

```
# Configure the AWS Provider
provider "aws" {
  region            = "us-east-1"
  use_fips_endpoint = true
}


terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = ">= 4.9.0"
    }

    local = {
      source  = "hashicorp/local"
      version = "~> 2.2.1"

    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0" #required terraform version
}
```

**S3 Module**
I did not include locals, outputs, or variables unless someone thinks we need to see them.  As I said before, the module was running correctly until today.  Hopefully, this is all you need for the provider's issue.  Let me know if other files are needed.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "buckets" {
  count         = length(var.bucket_names)
  bucket        = lower(replace(replace("${var.bucket_names[count.index]}-s3", " ", "-"), "_", "-"))
  force_destroy = var.bucket_destroy
  tags          = local.all_tags
}

# Set Public Access Block for each bucket
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "bucket_public_access_block" {
  count                   = length(var.bucket_names)
  bucket                  = aws_s3_bucket.buckets[count.index].id
  block_public_acls       = var.bucket_block_public_acls
  ignore_public_acls      = var.bucket_ignore_public_acls
  block_public_policy     = var.bucket_block_public_policy
  restrict_public_buckets = var.bucket_restrict_public_buckets
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "bucket_acl" {
  count  = length(var.bucket_names)
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.buckets[count.index].id
  acl    = var.bucket_acl
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "bucket_versioning" {
  count  = length(var.bucket_names)
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.buckets[count.index].id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "bucket_lifecycle_rule" {
  count  = length(var.bucket_names)
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.buckets[count.index].id
  rule {
    id = "${var.bucket_names[count.index]}-lifecycle-${count.index}"
    status = "Enabled"
    expiration {
      days = var.bucket_backup_expiration_days
    }
       
    transition {
      days          = var.bucket_backup_days
      storage_class = "GLACIER"
    }
  }
}

# AWS KMS Key Server Encryption
resource "aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration" "bucket_encryption" {
  count  = length(var.bucket_names)
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.buckets[count.index].id
  rule {
    apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
      kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.bucket_key[count.index].arn
      sse_algorithm     = var.bucket_sse
    }
  }
}
```

Looking for any other ideas I can use to fix this issue.  thank you!!

Comment: Please add the S3 code you have as well.

Comment: Please take a look has been updated per your request.

Answer (score 5):

Although you haven't included it in your question, I'm guessing that somewhere else in this Terraform module you have a block like this:

```
resource "s3_bucket" "example" {

}
```

For backward compatibility with modules written for older versions of Terraform, `terraform init` has some heuristics to guess what provider was intended whenever it encounters a resource that doesn't belong to one of the providers in the module's `required_providers` block. By default, a resource "belongs to" a provider by matching the prefix of its resource type name -- `s3` in this case -- to the local names chosen in the `required_providers` block.

Given a resource block like the above, `terraform init` would notice that `required_providers` doesn't have an entry `s3 = { ... }` and so will guess that this is an older module trying to use a hypothetical legacy official provider called "s3" (which would now be called `hashicorp/s3`, because official providers always belong to the `hashicorp/` namespace).

The correct name for this resource type is `aws_s3_bucket`, and so it's important to include the `aws_` prefix when you declare a resource of this type:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {

}
```

This resource is now by default associated with the provider local name "aws", which *does* match one of the entries in your `required_providers` block and so `terraform init` will see that you intend to use `hashicorp/aws` to handle this resource.

Comment: I updated the post like 5 minutes ago and added the s3 resource.  As I mentioned in my post, i have upgrade S3 with the latest resource changes that hashicorp provided.  Take a look at the latest update should show you what you asked for.

Comment: Indeed, sorry... you updated your question while I was already updating my answer, so the old version was on my screen when I hit submit but I saw your updated question after I'd already submitted it. I left it because it seemed like my guess was close enough to what you shared anyway. I'm glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

My colleague and I finally found the problem.  Turns out that we had a data call to the S3 bucket.  Nothing was wrong with the module but the place I was calling the module had a local.tf action where I was calling s3 in a legacy format see the change below:

**WAS**

```
data "s3_bucket" "MyResource" {}
```

**TO**

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "MyResource" {}
```

Appreciate the responses from everyone.  Resource was the root of the problem but forgot that data is also a resource to check.